# prevent the usage of top level area in TFS

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

Is it possible to somehow prevent the usage of the top level area (at least for a specific transition)? I tried to use the **"PROHIBITEDVALUES"** rule for **AreaPath and AreaId**, but they failed with error **`TF26062`**. I also tried to use **"WHEN"** rule for the State field, select AreaPath as field and specify the root Area as value, then use the **"PROHIBITEDVALUES"** rule to disallow a State, but I always get an error that I cannot do that.

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Comment: Do you mean you don't want to allow any people to create or move work item to the root area path?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly, it is true that there are some paticular fields which can't be applied rules.

> System fields are fields which have System.Name reference names, for
> example System. Title and System.State. **TFS restricts customization of
> these fields.**
>
> ***Source here: [System field rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/work/customize/reference/apply-rule-work-item-field#related-notes)***

The `System.AreaPath` is system field. So we canno apply the rules for it.

However as a workaround you can validate the Area Path, please refer to below link for more information: [Work Item Rules Workarounds: Validating Area Path](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/teams_wit_tools/2009/02/07/work-item-rules-workarounds-validating-area-path/)